# substitution in $\mathbb R^n$ :$\int_{\varphi(U)} f=\int_U f(\psi)|\det J_\psi|$. Why if taking $U$ closed instead of open the formula still hold?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification, substitution

The substitution in $\mathbb R^n$ goes as follow : If $\varphi: U\to \mathbb R^n$ is injective and $\mathcal C^1$ where $U\subset \mathbb R^n$ is open, and $f$ is continuous then $$\int_{\varphi(U)} f=\int_{U}f(\varphi)|\det J_\varphi|$$
where $J_\varphi$ is the Jacobian matrix of $\varphi$.

As a remark it's written that *"If $\varphi$ and $\varphi'$ can be extend continuously to $\bar U$, taking $\bar U$ instead of $U$ in the remark doesn't change the result"* and I tried to understand why.

Would it be for the following reason : If $U$ is open, then $\bar U=U\cup \partial U$ where $\partial U$ is the boundary of $U$. Since $\varphi$ is continuous and injective, we have that $\varphi(\bar U)=\varphi(U)\cup \partial \varphi(U)$ and since $U$ and $\varphi(U)$ are open, $\partial U$ and $\partial \varphi(U)$ has measure $0$, so finally

$$\int_{\varphi(\bar U)} f=\int_{\varphi(U)} f+\underbrace{\int_{\partial\varphi( U)}f}_{=0}=\int_{U}f(\varphi)|\det J_\varphi|=\int_{U}f(\varphi)|\det J_\varphi|+\underbrace{\int_{\partial U}f(\varphi)|\det J_\varphi|}_{=0}=\int_{\bar U}f(\varphi)|\det J_\varphi|.$$

**Question:** Is this the reason ?

Comment: I would imagine that you need some conditions on $U$? The boundary of an open set is not necessarily of measure zero (example, $\cup_k B(q_k, {1 \over 2^{k+2}})$ where $q_k$ is an enumeration of the rationals in $[0,1]$). The boundary is $[0,1]$.

Comment: @copper.hat: You right. Let say that in the case where the boundary of $U$ has measure $0$, does it work ? (I probably didn't wrote everything on my course)

Comment: You need $\phi$ to map null sets into null sets. If $\phi$ is Lipschitz on $U$ then this is true, for example. (As a related aside, look at Sard's theorem, this allows the formula to deal with non injective $\phi$ with some care.)

Comment: And for diffeomorphism, does it hold ? Because when I use the substitution, I in fact never really think if I'm talking the set open or closed, and it always works... @copper.hat

Comment: Hmm, I'd need to think about this a little, if you have $C^1$ diffeomorphism then it will be locally Lipschitz so it will work. You also need the boundary of $U$ to be a null set.

Comment: Thank you :) **1)** Just for simple example : consider for example $\varphi(r,\theta )=(r\cos \theta ,r\sin \theta )$ where $r\in [0,1]$, $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$. (normally we should talk $r\in ]0,1[$ and $\theta \in ]0,2\pi[$, but using $r\in [0,1]$ and $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$ it also work. **2)** Suppose we have all good condition (i.e. $\varphi$ transform null set in null set...), is my proof of the original post correct ?

Comment: It works because the boundaries have measure zero so they are irrelevant to the integrals. A sufficient condition (in addition to injectivity) is that the boundary of $U$ has measure zero and $\phi$ is $C^1$

Comment: @copper.hat: That's great. So in the case where $\partial U$ and $\varphi(\partial U)$ has measure $0$, my proof in my original post work ?

Comment: Looks reasonable, but there are some details missing, $f$ needs to be integrable or $U$ bounded or similar.